# Trying to do ng-click on dynamically loading image

Tags: angular

This image tag is dynamically created and I want to click on this image and have an alert popup but when I click on the image nothing happens and there is no alert that pops up. Also my console is not displaying errors.  This code is located in my controller.

event.img = angular.element(`<img src="${getDartImage(event)}"  ng-click="clicker()" class="dart">`);

This is the function called when button is clicked it is also located in my controller.

```
$ctrl.clicker = function()
    {
      alert("Inside controller: value of myval is ");


    }
```

Comment: It's [not working](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: I mean when I click on the image nothing happens and there is no alert that pops up.  Also my console is not displaying errors.

Comment: Edit this information into your question.

Comment: Where ever you dynamically add that image. Allways compile it to angular using the `$compile` service. Like so `$compile('<img src="/image.jpg" ng-click="clicker()" />')(scope);`. Without *compiling*, angular won't work on dynamically added content!

Comment: How do use $compile with angular.element because I need that to load the images?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Red